# No route matches [PUT] error in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

in active_admin partials created a form input:

```
<%= semantic_nested_form_for @item, :url => admin_items_path(@item) do |f| %>
  <fieldset class="inputs">
    <ol>
      <%= f.input :category %></br>
      <%= f.input :title  %>
      <%= f.input :photo1 %>
      <%= f.input :photo2 %>
    </ol>
  </fieldset>
  <%= f.fields_for :ItemColors do |i| %>
    <fieldset class="inputs">
      <ol>
        <%= i.input :DetailColor %>
        <%= i.input :size,  :input_html => { :size => "10" } %>
        <%= i.link_to_remove "remove" %>
      </ol>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.link_to_add "add", :ItemColors %>
  <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

to create a new Item okay creates and throws On the New Item, but if I do update an existing item is routed to an error occurs while such a path exists:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/admin/items.150" #150 is item_id
```

rake routes:

```
batch_action_admin_items POST   /admin/items/batch_action(.:format)   admin/items#batch_action
admin_items GET                 /admin/items(.:format)                admin/items#index
POST                            /admin/items(.:format)                admin/items#create
new_admin_item GET              /admin/items/new(.:format)            admin/items#new
edit_admin_item GET             /admin/items/:id/edit(.:format)       admin/items#edit
admin_item GET                  /admin/items/:id(.:format)            admin/items#show
PUT                             /admin/items/:id(.:format)            admin/items#update
DELETE                          /admin/items/:id(.:format)            admin/items#destroy
```

help to solve this problem

**UPD**

I found the error, but not yet understood how to fix it

the upgrade is a request:

```
PUT "/admin/items.150"
```

but should:

```
PUT "/admin/items/150"
```

I can not understand where the address appears "."

Answer (score 1):

Your form is submitting data with the `:method => POST` while your route is expecting `PUT`, `POST` only matches

```
POST /admin/items(.:format) admin/items#create
```

So it thinks that your ID is a `.:format` parameter. And thus failing. You need to change your form :method to `PUT` instead of `POST`.

Comment: If I set the method put: Error when updating does not change and there is the same under the action to create. And if I set the post method error updating is: Couldn't find ItemColor with ID=12 for Item with ID=

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do this:

```
<%= semantic_nested_form_for [:admin, @item] do |f| %>
```

As @cdesrosiers points out, the `No route matches [GET] "/items/152"` error you subsequently get is probably because you are redirecting to `@item` in your controller `create` and `update` actions, when you actually need to do this:

```
redirect_to admin_item_path(@item)
```

Comment: then: No route matches [GET] "/items/152"

Comment: Ah... then you need `:method => :put`, but of course that won't work with your `create` action which expects a POST. So... try `semantic_nested_form_for [:admin, @item]` with no url

Comment: problem at '.' in PUT "/admin/items.150"
I can not understand where it came from there

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. Did you try this? `<%= semantic_nested_form_for [:admin, @item] do |f| %>`

Comment: Weird. I think that this should "just work" when you write it like that. Can you try with Rails' own `form_for` and see if it does the same thing?

Comment: become more interesting) at :url => admin_items_path() work "Create Item", at :url => admin_item_path() work "Update Item"...

Comment: I suspect that your controller is updating the item correctly, but runs into the `[GET] /items/152` error when you then try to show the item. Do you have something like `redirect_to @item` in your `update` action? If so, change it to `redirect_to admin_item_path(@item)`, which will follow the correct path `[GET] admin/items/152`.

Comment: redirect working properly, the problem is the difference in creating request and update requesе. if I write: :url => admin_item_path() then when trying to create Item  I get: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/items"}